# Creating a vertical menu to show content on it's right

Tags: javascript, html, css, joomla, menu

i'm creating a joomla website, with a template created by me. On one of the pages i wanna create ( in the content div ) a vertical menu to show the clickable content on the right of it.

i have made one with custom html where i just insert the html code in a module, and the module in a article.

My menus code it's configured like this

```
<div1>
<div2>
</div2>
<div3>
</div3>
</div1>
```

where div2 and 3 are both with float left, (div2 being the menu with 30% width and div3 being the content with 70%). And i added a javascript so that when i click one of the menus it just fades the text in.

Basically what i want is this but wihtout tables: http://clinica.chip7.pt/servico_diagnostico_gratis.php

Comment: Not sure what your question is?

Comment: I edited my answer below, you can use html <li> to create click able link in your navigation bar to the left

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Made a example of what I think you are looking for based on your question, hard to tell.

**here is the demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/tATWE/1/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="outer-container">  
    <div id="header">  
        <h1>{ Header }</h1>  
    </div>  
    <div style="clear: both">  
    </div>  

    <div id="top-Nav">  
        <h1>{ Top Navigation }</h1>  
    </div>  
    <div style="clear: both">  
    </div>  

    <div id="left-nav">  
        <h1>{ Left Side Navigation }</h1>  
        <ul>
            <li>Nav Links</li>
            <li>Nav Links</li>
        </ul>
    </div>  
    <div id="content-container">  
        <h1>{ Content }</h1>  
    </div>  
    <div style="clear: both">  
    </div>  

    <div id="footer">  
        <h1>{ Footer }</h1>  
    </div>  
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {  
    margin: 0px;  
    padding: 0px;  
}  

/* h1 tag style */  
h1 {  
    margin: 0px;  
    padding: 0px;  
    font-family: arial;  
    font-size: 140%;  
    color: #fff;  
}  

/* CSS Style Rule for Div having id="outer-container" */  
/* outer-container will hold the whole assembly of  
   nested div overlays. */  
/* It will also center align the design */  
#outer-container {  
    width: 990px;  
    margin: 0 auto;  
}  

/* footer CSS Style Rule */  
#header {  
    width: 990px;  
    height: 90px;  
    background-color: blue;  
}  

/* footer CSS Style Rule */  
#footer {  
    width: 990px;  
    background-color: red;  
}  

/* content-container CSS Style Rule */  
/* It will hold the main content of the page. */  
/* it is the right side column */  
/* in this 2 columns div layout */  
#content-container {  
    width: 730px;  
    height: 400px;  
    background-color: green;  
    margin: 2px 0px 2px 0px;  
    float: left;  
}  

/* left side navigation that is the left side column of */  
/* 2 columns div layout */  
#left-nav {  
    width: 258px;  
    height: 400px;  
    background-color: navy;  
    margin: 2px 2px 2px 0px;  
    float: left;  
}
#left-nav li {  
    color: red;  
}  

/* Top navigation CSS Style Rule */  
#top-Nav {  
    width: 990px;  
    background-color: black;  
    margin: 2px 0px 0px 0px;  
}
```

Comment: Yes that's how my webiste looks . Altho, it's kinda messy because what i have is all the text in several different divs but javascript hides or shows them as i click the items in the menu . Is there a way to make it without javascript ? cause atm it's just a hugeeeeeee html code since so much text from each menu . http://datamaia.pt/index.php/serv this is the page i'm tyring to configure . take a look if you can .